# Post id(login page) not found

Tags: pages, login

I'm getting error when i access to page `?page_id=8`, but i have no errors in logs(or i don't know where are). Someone knows what happening?

I get a message like so:

> Oops! That page can’t be found.
>
> It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the
>   links below or a search?

I have the post created in database, and post id is 8.
In the database i have:
`[woocommerce_my_account]`

Thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: Hi,
Have you tried with reset permalinks or set page url in admin?
Please give a try. Thanks

Comment: Nothing, I restarted permanent links and have set the page in  administration and still getting error

Comment: Can you share the URL or provide more details about version of Woocoomerce, it is very difficult to assist without these info.

Comment: I've done changes in these files:
- wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php
-wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-term-functions.php
-wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php
-wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/orderby.php
-wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php
-wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/functions.php
-wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/woocommerce.php

Could be some file?

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in the functions.php file. Is already working, thanks otherwise for your time!